# DotNetNuke Admin and host controls giving errors

Tags: compilation, dotnetnuke

I am getting an error after upgrading DNN 6.X site to DNN 7.0.6 version, while accessing host pages and admin controls. I'd appreciate it if you have any idea how to solve this issue. The site is hosted on a shared server.

The error is:

> Error: is currently unavailable.
>   DotNetNuke.Services.Exceptions.ModuleLoadException: External component
>   has thrown an exception. ---> System.Web.HttpCompileException:
>   External component has thrown an exception. at
>   System.Web.Compilation.AssemblyBuilder.Compile() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildProvidersCompiler.PerformBuild() at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.CompileWebFile(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultInternal(VirtualPath
>   virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean allowCrossApp, Boolean
>   allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean throwIfNotFound, Boolean
>   ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.Compilation.BuildManager.GetVPathBuildResultWithNoAssert(HttpContext
>   context, VirtualPath virtualPath, Boolean noBuild, Boolean
>   allowCrossApp, Boolean allowBuildInPrecompile, Boolean
>   throwIfNotFound, Boolean ensureIsUpToDate) at
>   System.Web.UI.TemplateControl.LoadControl(VirtualPath virtualPath) at
>   DotNetNuke.UI.ControlUtilities.LoadControl[T](TemplateControl
>   containerControl, String ControlSrc) at
>   DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.WebFormsModuleControlFactory.CreateModuleControl(TemplateControl
>   containerControl, ModuleInfo moduleConfiguration) at
>   DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleControlFactory.LoadModuleControl(TemplateControl
>   containerControl, ModuleInfo moduleConfiguration) at
>   DotNetNuke.UI.Modules.ModuleHost.LoadModuleControl() --- End of inner
>   exception stack trace ---

Answer (score 0):

Not absolutely sure but can you try to temporarily remove all files in the App_code folder and see if you still get this error. I think the compiler only fires up when there is source code in that folder.

It could also be an asp.net version conflict, DotNetNuke 7 needs asp.Net 4 where DotNetNuke supported Asp.Net 3.5, you can probably verify that in your hosting control panel.